# How can I exclude null rows in a MatLab table?

Tags: matlab, null, row

I have a matrix with m rows and n columns where `p` rows `(p<m)` are null.

How can I do to exclude these null rows?

Let be

```
 6     6     2
 6     2     2
 4     5     4
 1     2     3
 1     6     3
 2     3     5
 0     0     0  
 0     0     0
```

the matrix. So, I need exclude the two last rows.

Tks for your help.

Comment: Refer to the duplicate, but operate on the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`any`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) for this purpose as follows:

```
A = A(any(A,2),:);
% any(A,2) gives the logical indices of the rows whose at least one element is non-zero
```